# Cordova google maps, iOS9, tiles won't load

Tags: ios, cordova, google-maps

[image]

Under iOS 9.3, this is all I get, with no errors in the xcode console except `cdvwebviewdelegate navigation started when state=1`.

I am also unable to attach safari to the emulator to try and get the console output.

I am guessing it's content security policy related, but I don't know any way to see what it is trying to access.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by chance, the error also happened on my old nexus 7 2012 tablet running jellybean. I was able to hook it up to the debugger and found the content security problem.

img-src 'self' data: https://*.gstatic.com http://*.googleapis.com **https://*.googleapis.com** blob: content:

I didn't have an https version, and the maps were loading as https, not http.  DOH! I don't think I even need the http version.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*.google.com" />
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't seem to have any effect, both `<allow-navigation href="http://*.google.com" />` and `<allow-navigation href="https://*.google.com" />`